# install new plugins to jenkins from cli in docker jenkins set up

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a jenkins server running from docker container. Based off of https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine and using version-specific values. I'm planning to have few more plugins by updating plugins.txt as I cannot install plugins from jenkins UI. 
My question is how can I make these new changes effective after restarting jenkins and without loosing existing jobs on jenkins server. How to rebuild the image or container so that my new changes are effective?